# Nowhere dense set in the proof of global rank theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading and trying to understand John Lee's proof of the Global Rank Theorem in his Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.But I don't see why the highlighted part in the image is true.
[image: 1]

Comment: The fact that $F(\overline{U})$ is compact follows from $\overline{U}$ being compact. Also, Since the set $y^{r+1}=...=y^{n}=0$ is (after applying $\psi$) a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, it has empty interior. Hope this helps!

Comment: @DarthLubinus That's exactly the point.Thanks!