# Global rank Theorem nowhere Dense set.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

My question is similar to the one posted here [Nowhere dense set in the proof of global rank theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3861762/nowhere-dense-set-in-the-proof-of-global-rank-theorem), the response they got seemed to have been exactly what they needed, but still left me a little lost.
it is in relation to the proof of the global rank theorem in Lee's "Smooth Manifolds", it is the first part of the proof where he is dealing with submersions. I understand up until the part where we shrink $U$ so that $\overline{U}$ will be compact and since the continuous image of a compact set is compact we have $F(\overline{U})\subseteq V$ is compact. Then he says

"$F(\overline{U})$ is a compact subset of $\{y\in V:y^{r+1}=\cdots=y^n=0\}$ , so it is closed
in N and contains no open subset of N; hence it is nowhere dense in N."

This is a little strange to me, I am thinking the set is supposed to be representing something like $\{y^{r+1},\dots,y^n\in \big(V,(y^1,\dots,y^n)\big):y^{r+1}(V)=\cdots =y^{n}(V)=0\}\subset \mathbb{R}^{n-r}$?
because the first notation looks like it is saying something about the points in $V$ and then relating it to the coordinate functions of a chart $(V,\psi)$ where he lets $\psi=(y^1,\dots,y^n)$, but the real confusion happens next with it being closed in $N$ and containing no open subsets of $N$, I am not sure how that is the case, right now, it looks like a level set to me, I understand the preimage of the closed singleton $\{0\}$ will be closed under a continuous map, but I am not sure why it would have no open subsets in $N$? And since the derived contradiction heavily depends this fact I really want to be able to make sense of it.

Comment: $N$ is a "slice" in $\mathbb{R}^n$, like a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, can you find an open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is contained in a plane?

Comment: Ok, so the notation I have there seems to be correct, representing it as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n-r}$? I guess maybe what I am not seeing, is that $\{y^{r+1},\dots,y^n\in (V,(y^1,\dots,y^n)):y^{r+1}(V)=\cdots=y^n(V)=0\}$  doesn't contain the first $r$ coordinate functions. I was thinking the first $r$ could take on whatever values, just that the last $n-r$ were required to by zero mappings so a more accurate representation of what I was envisioning is $\mathbb{R}^r\times\mathbb{R}^{n-r}$.

Comment: And it won't have open neighborhoods in $\mathbb{R}^n$ because we can't find n-balls around any point.  Does this pullback to $N$ though?

Comment: $\{y\in V:y^{r+1}=\cdots=y^n=0\}$ means the points in $V$ such that the last $n-r$ coordinates (under homeomorphism $\psi$) are $0$. So under the homeomorphism $\psi$, this set is exactly the points in $\psi(V)$ whose last $n-r$ coordinates are $0$. It has no open sets in Euclidean space, neither does its homeomorphic image .

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I was trying to describe, for each $p\in V$ we have $\psi(p)=(x_1,\dots,x_r,0\dots,0)$, or something like $\psi(V)=U\times 0$ with $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{r}$. But that doesn't help the issue I am having, for instance, we know that the constant functions are smooth, if that constant is $0$ in analogy with this, then the codomain of the function has no open subset, but the preimage is the whole space. I am having a hard time seeing how the information in the codomain, carries over into the domain in this case.

Comment: Maybe you need this property? : Let $X, Y$ be two homeomorphic topological spaces, $\psi$ is the homeomorphism map. $A$ is a subset of $X$ and  $B = \psi(A)$. Then $A$ is nowhere dense in $X$ iff $B$ is nowhere dense in $Y$. Now $\psi(\{y\in V:y^{r+1}=\cdots=y^n=0\})$ is nowhere dense in $\psi(V)$, therefore $\{y\in V:y^{r+1}=\cdots=y^n=0\}$ is nowhere dense in $V$, which also implies it's nowhere dense in $N$.

Comment: You are correct, I have not seen this statement. But a google search of that statement did not produce any results, is there a proof for this?

Comment: One direction: $A$ is nowhere dense in $X$ means $\overline{A}$ contains no nonempty open set of $X$. Assume that $\overline{\psi(A)}=\psi(\overline{A})$ contains an nonempty open set $V$ in $Y$, then $\overline{A}$ contains an nonempty open set $\psi^{-1}(\overline{V})$, which is a contradiction. In differential geometry, such properties are often used without explicit explanation and not very difficult to prove: you can view the chart in manifold the same thing as its homeomorphic image in Euclidean space.